# NetSuite Abandoned Carts Follow Up Email

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to find the SuiteApp Product Abandoned Carts Follow Up Email from the backend of NetSuite. Does this come pre loaded or is there something that we need to install or purchase to get this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a workflow or script it out as far as I know....will edit with more details soon